# Unable to access vuex-orm $db variable from store in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-orm

Using nuxtjs with vuexorm & vuexorm-axios plugin.

> /pages/index.vue

```
computed: {
  users() {
 // this works as expected
  return User.all()
  }
    }
```

> plugins/vuex-orm-axios.js

```
import { Model } from '@vuex-orm/core'

export default ({ $axios }) => {
  Model.setAxios($axios)
}
```

> store/index.js

```
import VuexORM from '@vuex-orm/core'
import VuexORMAxios from '@vuex-orm/plugin-axios'
import User from '@/models/user'


VuexORM.use(VuexORMAxios)


// Create a new database instance.
const database = new VuexORM.Database()

// Register Models to the database.
database.register(User)


export const plugins = [
  VuexORM.install(database)
]
```

Above all works. But in vuexorm [docs](https://vuex-orm.github.io/vuex-orm/guide/digging-deeper/server-side-rendering.html) it says to always fetch model from injected database instance for nuxt/ssr apps.
But if I try to access the `$db` variable from `store` it wont work as there is no $db variable inside store.

> /pages/index.vue

```
computed: {
  users() {
 // this wont work as $db is undefined
    User () {
     return this.$store.$db().model('users')
    },
    users () {
     return this.User.all()
    }

    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In your `store/index.js` you have to export `state` to activate Vuex store. Add this to the file:

```
export const state = () => ({})
```